# Users with most posts edited

Tags: support, users, top-users

I've seen several Stack Overflow users like [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan?tab=topactivity) with a huge amount of edited posts (12,000+) which I think is really impressive.

I'm very curious and would like to know if there is anything that I can use to find users with a very high amount of edited posts like that.

I've tried searching in the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=most+post+edited) but couldn't seem to find anything.

Comment: Make your own SEDE query?

Comment: i have no idea how to do that, i'll try to learn it later :D

Comment: [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and [SEDE help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: There is [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476172).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can visit the **Users** page and order by **Editors** for the **all** interval:

[image: Screenshot of how to navigate to the top editors page. 1. Users in the side menu. 2. "Editors" at the top. 3. Choose "all" as the interval]

[Here is a direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all)

An alternative is to write a SEDE query. You can see the [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and [SEDE help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) for getting started.

Comment: First place atm is really disappointing. Seen them correct grammar in thanks and other salutations :facepaw:

Comment: @Zoe were you perhaps expecting poetry? :)

Comment: @Gimby Probably wanted them to remove content that's considered noise instead of correcting it.

Comment: @BSMP oh man, I completely misread that comment! I read "correct grammar AND thanks and salutations". Correct grammar IN thanks and salutations is a world of difference.